# Changing the limits of integration from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, error-function

Is it fair to change from

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{a} \exp \left( -t^2 \right) \mathrm dt
$$

replacing $t$ with $-t$
$$
\int_{-a}^{\infty} \exp \left( -t^2 \right) \mathrm dt
$$

and thus gaining the advantage of being able to use the complementary error function.

Comment: The lower limit in the second integral should be $-a$.

Comment: Since the integration variable doesn't appear in the integrand, it's $\infty$ anyway ...

Comment: What is $\text{s}$? Does $t$ have some dependence on it?

Comment: As an aside, you could also write $$\int_{-\infty}^a = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \int_{a}^{+\infty}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the variable 
$$t\mapsto -t$$ 
implies the following change in the integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a\exp(-t^2)\,dt=-\int_{\infty}^{-a}\exp(-t^2)\,dt=\int_{-a}^\infty\exp(-t^2)\,dt.
$$